# Hazelcast embedded, local or in process example

Tags: local, hazelcast

I would like to use Hazelcast as cache embedded, local or in process. I think that these three concepts are the same.

Is it a correct example?

```java
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
ICacheManager cacheManager = hz.getCacheManager();
ICache<String, CaLpgDataCollectionDto<CaBigNumber>> icache = cacheManager.getCache("Test");
icache.put("Test1",lpgDatasource);
CaLpgDataCollectionDto<CaBigNumber> testDatasource = icache.get("Test1");
```

If not. I would like to see one.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is the correct embedded usage of Hazelcast cache.

You can find many more samples at [Hazelcast code samples repository](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/). Especially [`JCache` samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/examples) if you are interested in caching api.